# Errors In Every Project In Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I did something in eclipse which caused 282 errors. There are tons of errors in pretty much every project, including the Facebook SDK library which leads me to believe it's not something I did in a particular project.

I'm not exactly sure what caused it, but the last few things I remember doing were this.

I was having issues with combining code from 2 .java files to make one .java file with both functions, and I started to have r.java errors. I tried doing things like cleaning the project, etc and so that might have had something to do with it.

The other thing I did recently was get rid of the majority of appcompat_v7 folders and relink them all to the same original one.. I had about 14, starting from appcompat_V7_2, leading up to 14. I read that if I deleted them all except the first one,  appcompat_v7, I could just relink them all to that one and it would work. I think that could have caused these but I don't think I can undo it.

Here is a screenshot - [Screenshot Of Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vB3y.jpg)

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know. Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried restarting eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I have tried restarting eclipse and cleaning/rebuilding all the projects.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have deleted a dependency of your major work.

You are correct in that there is no undo...you need to re-link the correct dependencies.

According to your question, it would be appcompat_v7. 
If you re-link it to your projects and it still throwing errors, you need to look through your other dependencies (the ones you deleted) and find which contain the missing functions/etc and re-link them as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the paths has changed, because Eclipse can't find some resources.
Check if this is correct path to them.
Check if you have capital letters there where it should be.

Also try to import that project to NetBeans and run it.
If in NB runs than the problem is in build paths